# PHP check if user is logged in [best practice]

Tags: php, authorization, session-variables

I'm creating a user portal for our customers but I'm yet to find the best way to check if a user is logged in or not. I used to check it by setting some session variables with my authenticate() function:

```
 public function authenticate($customerId, $password) {
    $user = $this->findById($customerId);

    if(!$this->pkdf->verify_password($password, $user->getHash())) {
        return false;
    } 

    $_SESSION['user']['customerid'] = $user->getId();
    $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $user->getEmailNormal();
}
```

Then I check with

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) { 
    // logout code 
}
```

if the user is allowed to visit the page.

But someone said to me that I should not be using session variables for authorization, instead I should take a look at access tokens in the header. I don't know where to look further, can anyone push me into the right direction, possible with some example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498803/session-are-not-working/37498958#37498958

Comment: @Yahoo That question does not apply to mine, I have no trouble getting my sessions to work, but I'm asking if this is the right way to authorise my users.

Comment: Then you should send it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Beeelze. But that was another good method.Also read this from Larry ullman forum. http://larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/2916-secure-session-best-practices/

Comment: @Yahoo Oh, do you mean something like  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        } ? I'm still checking on sessions right, or is this the only way.

Comment: @nanodanger Might be considered stub code there. Not sure whether it's a good fit. See their [help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).